# Is there a standard way to handle passwords within REST resources

Tags: api, rest

Imagine we have a REST service that has a resource, that contains a password (or some other sensitive information). Once the password is set, we never want to return it through API (after it is set, only some external system will use it, we may be storing only hash of the password, etc).

So we have a PUT/POST request that sends in a resource with a password. What should GET request return? I could think of few possible solutions:

1. GET could return same resource, but without password field (Feels
   strange, since password is a valid field for PUT/POST, so why not
   GET)
2. GET could return resource, but with the password field empty or
   set to some arbitrary value.
3. Have password removed from resource, and have a child resource.
   e.g. resource/password, to which we can PUT password, but on which there is not GET request allowed.

This seems like a fairly common problem, but I cannot seem to find a good, standard way to solve it. Most of the search results point to actual passwords for users accessing the API, and resetting those, which is not the case here. Is there common, well-established way to handle this case?

Comment: Would this be an appropriate use case for 451?

Answer (score 0):

You can `POST`/`PUT` data and not return it in the response or in a `GET`.
My choice would be #1 Return the resource without the field.
Also ok to use #2 and obfuscate the field.